# Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't respond to click after calling toggle method

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have some Bootstrap Dropdown elements in my navbar that should hide if the user scrolls. However, after calling the toggle method on the dropdown clicking on the dropdown no longer toggles the dropdown.

After pageload you can scroll the page and repeatedly toggle dropdowns via click. If you scroll while a dropdown is open the JS closes the open dropdown.  After that point you cannot toggle that dropdown via click. Other dropdowns continue to toggle until you scroll while the dropdown is open.

```
<nav>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dropdown-header"></span>About Our Company</a>
    <div role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section class="widget menu-post-widget-2 menu-post-widget-class">
                    <div class="row">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</nav>
```

The JS:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    // Close the drop down on scroll
    $('nav .dropdown.open').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: It feels like you're using jQuery, when you could just be using bootstrap's built-in methods?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I am using this as intended: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-methods